# Regex - What's the difference between [\V], [^\v]?

Tags: regex, tabs, notepad++

I know "\v" means vertical tab or whitespaces (LF,CR, etc) in regex, so I've used [^\v] instead of [\V] to indicate any character which is not vertical whitespace. But I found the case that [^\v] didn't work in notepad++ 7.5.

Example text source ( ffmpeg log )

```
frame=13920 fps= 86 q=-1.0 size=   96512kB time=00:07:44.47 bitrate=1702.2kbits/s speed=2.88x    
frame=14068 fps= 87 q=-1.0 size=   98048kB time=00:07:49.41 bitrate=1711.1kbits/s speed= 2.9x    
frame=14116 fps= 87 q=-1.0 Lsize=   98954kB time=00:07:51.06 bitrate=1720.9kbits/s speed=2.91x    
video:86252kB audio:3826kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 9.852874%
```

I want to capture the value of latest or last speed of ffmpeg process, so I applied a regex like follows

```
(?s).*speed=\s*\K([^\v]*)(?=x.*$)
```

and returned capture value in notepad++ is

```
2.91x    
video:86252kB audio:3826kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB mu
```

but, [regex101.com result](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/3) is "2.91", the value I expected.

So I tried [\V] like follows

```
(?s).*speed=\s*\K([\V]*)(?=x.*$)
```

Then, both all returned the same captured value I expected, "2.91".
 [regex101's result](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/4)

Therefore, I'm wondering about the difference between [\V], [^\v] and why notepad++ matched so differently. Thank you:-)

Comment: `\w` and `\W` are generally supported, it's not a single character but a representation of many, just as `\s` and `\S` are, but I'm not sure `\v` works the same way. I'd expect `[\V]` to be equivalent to `[V]`.

Comment: But in the case of applying [\V], both 101.com and notepad++ returned same value 2.91. So I think it means that [\V] acts something like [^\v] indicating any character which is not vertical-tab.

Comment: `\v` represents the "vertical tab character", or ASCII 11. This is not the same as either carriage return (ASCII 13) or linefeed (ASCII 10).

Comment: If [\V] is equivalent to [V] , the words including "v" after "speed=" are "video" and "overhead" in the last line. Why could be such results ?

Comment: It's case-sensitive, and you have no capital *V* letters. I'm not sure what the `\K` is all about either.

Comment: In notepad++, case-sensitive option is not applied in my test. And now in regex101.com, I applied (?i) to the two regex patterns and both all result in the same as the case which case-insensitive option (?i) not applied. And from my experience, I think that \K is applicable to both notepad++ and regex101.com.

Comment: There's a difference between "acceptable" and "meaningful". `\q` is just a letter `q`, not anything special. `\K` means *literal uppercase K*, nothing more as far as I can tell, so `K` should serve the same purpose as `\K`.

Comment: Notepad++ uses Boost regex library, and in regex101, you are using PCRE regex flavor. In PCRE, `[^\v]` seems to be parsed as a "non-vertical whitespace", but Boost parses `\v` inside a character class in another way, as a VT symbol, `\x0B`, `[^\v]` matches any chars but VT. Use `[^\r\n]` as a workaround that will work in most cases.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your claim controverts Notepad++ [documentation on RegEx](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: @revo Then the docs controvert the app. I tested all the patterns in the application.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's truly a case on Boost but I didn't find a reference for it except https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ uses [Boost regex library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html), and in regex101, you are using [PCRE regex flavor](https://pcre.org/pcre.txt). In PCRE, `[^\v]` seems to be parsed as a "non-vertical whitespace", but Boost parses `\v` inside a character class as a `VT` symbol, `\x0B`. The `[^\v]` negated character class matches any chars but `VT`.

Use `[^\r\n]` as a workaround that will work in most cases across a lot of regex flavors:

```
(?s).*speed=\s*\K([^\r\n]*)(?=x.*$)
                  ^^^^^^^
```

Or, in your case, use a `(?s:...)` modifier group with the first `.*` to make `.` match vertical whitespace, while the other `.*` will not match line breaks:

```
(?s:.*)speed=\s*\K(.*)(?=x.*$)
^^^^^^^
```

See [Mode Modifiers within Non-Capture Groups](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#nocap-with-modifier) to learn more about `(?smix:...)` constructs.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and good suggestions. But, also in notepad++, it seems [\V] works well in regex to indicate any character which is not vertical whitespace. Until now, I was under a delusion from my lapse of memory that [^\v] works in notepad++. But it's that I mistook "lazy quatifier" effect for it.

Comment: Yes, `\V` works the same as `[\V]`, but `\v` does not work the same as `[\v]`. I agree it is inconsistent, but cannot help that.

Answer (score 0):

The expression you want is probably this:

```
speed=\s*(\d+(?:.\d+)?)x?
```

For strings of the form `speed= 2.9x` and `speed=19.2x` and `speed= 1x`

Comment: I'm sorry to say that it results in "invalid regular expression" in both notepad++ and regex101.com. Would you mean something like this? **speed=\s*(\d+(\.?)\d*)x?** In fact, I used simpler pattern in the capturing group of the above case before like follows. .. ([^x]*)x  instead of ([^\v]*)x

Comment: I had an extra \ in there for some reason, fixed.